# How do I lock all cells of a copied workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, locking

I am trying to create a copy of my workbook when saving but when I create that copy, lock all cells so they can't be changed.

Here is what I have...

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim FName As String
Dim FPath As String
Dim NewBook As Workbook

FPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" '& FName
FName = "Saved File" & Format(Date, "YYMMDD") & ".xlsx"

Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & FName, FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & FName, FileFormat:=51

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
NewBook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can use `usedrange.locked` to lock the entire used range of the new workbook. However this does not prevent editing until the workbook is protected, so best to do that as well with `worksheet.protect`. Full code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim FName As String
Dim FPath As String
ThisWorkbook.Activate
FPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" '& FName
FName = "Saved File" & Format(Date, "YYMMDD") & ".xlsx"


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Locked = True
.Sheets(1).Protect ""
.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & FName, FileFormat:=51
.Close
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Note, `usedrange` is normally not the best practise to cover the entire range as it sometimes goes too large. However in your case you need to make sure all cells in the sheet are covered. Since all cells are protected by default when unchanged, `usedrange` will do the trick here nicely for the rest.

Edit, I glossed over most of the code as only the `protect` was relevant to the question. However as per comments, this leads to an issue. What happens is that you create a new workbook, and then copy the workbook with your code. This automatically creates a new workbook as well. This is the one which is saved, and `newbook` is closed without anything changed to it. I removed this part of the code. `ActiveWorkbook` after you copy should be the one containing your copied data, so I made this the one being locked and saved.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your answer. I do have an issue with this though. It locks and protects my current workbook rather than my copied workbook. Is there a way I can get it to lock and protect the worksheet in the copied workbook? Thanks

Comment: @JGoode This was caused by inefficiencies in your code I didn't look at. I've fixed them and it should work properly now.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to VBA. This no longer protects and locks my current Workbook. However, it still doesn't lock my copied workbook.

Comment: Sorry that's on me. I got the order wrong, and protected it after saving, meaning the protect action wasn't saved. Answer updated with the save after the protect. Should all work now. FYI: `application.displayalerts` should always be put in last, since it makes spotting errors like these a lot harder. (not blaming you, just some advice)

Comment: Ah, works perfectly! Thank you so much.
I got the base code from somewhere else so I didn't know any different. Useful to know though!